# How to set ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.Name from Claim with custom type in ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I use JWT Bearer to secure my WebApi endpoints.  All works fine so far but I am wondering why the "Name" property of the `ClaimsIdentity` of the `ClaimsPrincipal` is null.
I can remember somewhere to find the information, that this property is set from the content of a `Claim` of type "name" (correct???).  I have a Claim of type "username" in my JWT that contains the username and I try to find a way to map that into the `HttpContext.User.Identy.Name` property.

Is there any configuration for that?

EDIT:
The whole project is only for educational purposes, that is the reason for the quite simple code...

This is how I set the `Claim`:

```
private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
{
    // generate token that is valid for 7 days
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.JwtSecret);

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new("id", user.Id.ToString()),
        new("username", user.Username)
    };

    if (user.Username == "pbrause")
        claims.Add(new("weatherForecast", "true"));

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        Issuer = "me",
        Audience = "you",
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
        IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

Comment: how do you set the claim?

Answer (score 4):

I use `ClaimTypes.Name` as key and `user.username` as value to set the claim, Then i can get user name in `HttpContext.User.Identy.Name`.

```
 List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                        
         //..........
     };
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I am really after is a way to use some custom claim type   to map to `HttpContext.User.Identy.Name`.

Comment: I get your point, I find this [issue](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html), I tried it,  But it seems not work in my project,I'm not sure if it was unsuccessful because I was using .net 6

Answer (score 2):

In method where you call `AddJwtBearer` or something else you could customize it with `TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType`

Example:

```
services.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
             {
                 ...
                 o.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "username";
                 ...
              })
```

Answer (score 2):

Like described in this [blogpost](https://www.benday.com/2021/08/13/3-common-problems-with-claimsidentity-and-claimsprincipal-in-asp-net-core/), you have to specify the custom name property in the ClaimsIdentity constructor. If you want to have

```
new Claim("username", user.Username)
```

for the Identity Name property populated, you have to use the constructor

```
Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, ClaimTypes.Authentication, "username",  ClaimTypes.Role),
```

Notice the **"username"** string.